# Word / Excel templates that can grab information from a database

Tags: database, excel, templates, ms-word

I work for a small company that uses simple word / excel templates to write memos/reports and similar documents. I'm looking for more information about how to accomplish this task.

We would most likely need some sort of database to store all the necessary information (client name, contact info, etc...), and perhaps a series of sophisticated word and excel templates to extract information from the database.

At this point I am simply researching possible ways to tackle this. Perhaps there is some Microsoft software (or other vendor) that has this functionality built in?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MS Access, but I would really recommend using SQL Server instead.

Comment: So SQL server for the database and use built in word / excel functionality to grab info?

Comment: sure, using Excel it is relatively easy to pull information out of a database, using Word you can do mail merges.. I was literally doing that in 1981 in Word 1.0 or something crazy like that.

SQL Server is free.. it's a great engine.. but it's really a question of how many records you have / what you're trying to do.

Long term, SQL is safer for your data than MS Access.. but short term, it might really help you try to learn MS Access.

I'd probably try to avoid using Word, and try to build your reports that can be exported to word.. that's what I think is easiest.

Comment: SQL Server is not free, but it has a Express edition that can be used without payment

Comment: When you say avoid using Word, and build reports that can be exported to word, could you elaborate on that? Build them in access?

Currently we have an SQL database (most likely express) that stores client information. We probably have around 3000-8000 entries, each with about 10 pieces of information associated with it.

Thanks